# Shoot RayCast At Target Object

Tags: unity-game-engine

I want to shoot a raycast on target object without considering current object rotation and movement.

At present my raycast is hitting in the wrong direction, here is an example:

[image]

Currently, raycast is hitting in wrong direction, I want it to hit another player object.

I have written this code up to now for this purpose:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < gamePlayersList.Count; i++)
    {
        // if player is not same then do raycast to detect
        if (gamePlayersList[i] != transform)
        {
            Vector3 targetDir = gamePlayersList[i].position - transform.position;
            float rayAngle = Vector3.Angle(targetDir, transform.forward);

            Vector3 straightRayDirection = Quaternion.AngleAxis(rayAngle, Vector3.up) * transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward);
            Ray straightRay = new Ray(transform.position + Vector3.up, straightRayDirection);

            Debug.DrawRay(straightRay.origin, straightRay.direction * detectDistance, Color.red);

            //RaycastHit hit;
            //if (Physics.Raycast(straightRay, out hit, detectDistance, playersLayerMask))
            //{

            //}
        }
    }
```

Both tank objects are continuously moving and I want to detect them continuously through raycast.

So how to achieve this?

Comment: just use `targetDir`, it already is a vector pointing in the direction of the target.

Comment: I don't understand if you just want to shoot a ray from x to y why not just use: `Physics.Raycast(tankWhoIsShooting, targetedTank);` two paremeters are both `Vector3`

Comment: @Menyus probably because targetedTank is a position and not a direction? just beacuse the type is the same, doesnt mean it represents the same thing.

Comment: @yes then, `Physics.Raycast(tankWhoIsShooting, targetedTank - tankWhoIsShooting);`

Answer (score 1):

In your case i would just use [LineCast](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Linecast.html)

Since you only would like to know if you can "see" the enemy object or not, aka there is a collider or not.

```
for (int i = 0; i < gamePlayersList.Count; i++)
{
    // if player is not same then do raycast to detect
    if (gamePlayersList[i] != transform)
    {
        Vector3 targetDir = gamePlayersList[i].position;
        Vector3 myPosition = transform.position;

        Debug.DrawLine(myPosition, targetDir, Color.red);

        //RaycastHit hit;
        //if (Physics.Linecast(myPosition, targetDir))
        //{

        //}
    }
}
```

Linecast has also layer mask and some more just read the doc :)